# Dúvidas de sobre criação de API

Tags: api

Estou estudando e tentando entender o desenvolvimento de uma API, porém tenho algumas dúvidas...

1 - Qual linguagem/ferramenta vocês recomendam para a criação de uma API ? Estou usando o Slim Framework para aprender, é uma boa ideia ?

2 - Qual a diferença de API Key privada e pública ? Quando usar ? E por que alguns softwares possuem chaves publicas e privadas ?

3 - Estou querendo desenvolver uma API de atualização, ou seja, meu software vai consultar a minha API para ver se há atualizações a serem feitas e brevemente irá instalar essa atualização. A ideia de API é uma boa para esse caso, ou não ?

Obrigado.